# Unit Test - Query to fetch Event.who.name

Tags: unit-test, query, contact, event

I have an issue for my unit test where i seem to not being able to query the who.name from the Event record. For some reason, even after inserting the Event and querying it, it still gives me that the event.who.name is Null ... Even though it is set from the beginning and when querying the name from the Contact, it can find that, but not from the Event. What exactly is the issue here, and how can I cover my class?

the simplified code looks like this:

```
    public class queryTest {
    
    public static List<Event> searchQuery2(String searchName) {
        String personName = '%' + searchName + '%';
        List<Event> listOfEvents = new List<Event>();
        
        listOfEvents=[SELECT Id,Subject,AccountId,StartDateTime,Hub_Name__c,Sub_Type__c,
                       TYPEOF Who WHEN Contact THEN name END 
                     FROM Event WHERE who.name = :personName];
        
        return listOfEvents;  
    }
}
```

This is the simplified test method:

```
    @isTest
    public static void testQuerymethod() {
        
        List<Event> queriedEvents = new List<Event>();
        
        Account acc = new Account(Country__pc = 'GB', FirstName = 'Jack', LastName = 'Jackson' RecordTypeId = personAccountId);
        insert acc;
        Contact persContact = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Jackson'];
        System.debug('name of perContact' + persContact.Name);
        
        
        Event evt = new Event(
            Subject = 'Test',
            StartDateTime = DateTime.now().addDays(-2),
            EndDateTime = DateTime.now().addDays(-2).addMinutes(30),
            WhatId = acc.Id,
            WhoId = persContact.Id
        );
        insert evt;
        System.debug('evt.who.Name' + evt.who.name);
        Event evt2 = [SELECT Id, who.name FROM Event WHERE Subject = 'Test this event' LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('queried name event' + evt2.who.name);
        
        Test.startTest();
        queriedEvents = queryTest.searchQuery2('Jack');
        System.debug('evt who name ' + queriedEvents[0].who.name);
        System.assertEquals(1, queriedEvents.size());
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
```

Comment: `persContact` will be empty as you never mock it

Comment: The Account created is a Person Account. From which the Contact is automatically created.

Comment: but you query for the Contact before inserting the `acc`

Comment: i see, . It's correct now. But still same error. 
For some reason when querying for the Contact.Name, it shows me the name. But when querying for the Event.Who.Name, it still gives me null ...

Comment: this might be a Person Account thing as it works fine for non-person accounts. As I am not a person account user; I defer to someone else on the Community .  If you use the UX to create an event for a Person Account what does the SOQL do if executed in Developer Console?